# How to automatically add dev configuration files from one git repo to present project

Tags: git

I believe this this a very common thing to do but that I'm not making the question properly and therefore that's why I can't find any answers online.

I'm learning React Native (but this is a general question to any project) and I find myself copying some config files that I adapted to my tooling (in this case `.editorconfig`, `package.json`, `.babelrc`, etc...) every time I create a new project.

Now, this is getting cumbersome to remember which packages to add when I create a new project in React Native, so the obvious solution is to keep a git repo with just these configuration files (`.editorconfig`, `package.json`, `.babelrc`, etc...) and then after I create a new project with react native just get these few files into the new repo created.

How do I achieve this?

Comment: what are you trying to achieve?

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like you want to maintain a skeleton repo, something with boilerplate code that you can fill in, like [react-boilerplate](https://github.com/mxstbr/react-boilerplate).

Really all you're looking to do - as best as I can tell, since it's not entirely clear - is set up a repository that tracks these common files, and then to start another project with it, just do:

```
git clone my-boilerplate-repository
git remote remove origin
```

And now you have a copy of your boilerplate that's not linked to the boilerplate repository.

Comment: YEs, I think it's exactly that that you are suggesting, but what is the order I must use here (in this case related directly to react native) ? 1-Create new project by running `react-native init myproject`; 2-`git clone my-boilerplate-repository`; 3-`git remote remove origin` 4-init versioning for my new project with`git init`. Is this correct?

Comment: This assumes that `my-boilerplate-repository` already contains your boilerplate code. If you need to *create* your boilerplate code, you'll want to commit everything to `my-boilerplate-repository` before you can `clone` it out. I'm not familiar with `react-native` unfortunately, but if it's anything like `npm` projects (where you only track `package.json` in Git and use `npm` to manage the dependencies themselves), you'll want to do that *after* `clone`.